# Check if a polynomial is primitive over a galois field using Magma calculator

Tags: finite-fields, primitive-roots, magma-cas

I want to check if the polynomial $f(x) = 1 + x^{18} + x^{29} + x^{42} + x^{57} + x^{67} + x^{80}$ is primitive over the Galois Field $GF(2^{80})$ using the Magma Calculator (http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). I have the written the following two scripts to help me verify this. Script 1's output is $false$, while Script 2's output is $true$. Can someone explain why that is?
I read through the handbook of functions provided with the calculator (https://www.math.uzh.ch/sepp/magma-2.25.2-ds/HandbookVolume13.pdf), but that wasn't able to help me explain the difference between the two scripts.

**Script 1** :

```
K := GF(2^80);
R<x> := PolynomialRing(K);

f :=  1 + x^18 + x^29 + x^42 + x^57 + x^67 + x^80;

IsPrimitive(f);
```

**Script 2** :

````
K<x> := GF(2^80);

f :=  1 + x^18 + x^29 + x^42 + x^57 + x^67 + x^80;

IsPrimitive(f);
```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object $\ f\ $ in your first script is a polynomial of degree $80$ in the indeterminate $\ x\ $ over the field $\ GF\left(2^{80}\right)\ $. It's primitive if and only if all its roots are primitive elements of the field $\ GF\left(\left(2^{80}\right)^{80}\right)=$$\,GF\left(2^{6400}\right)\ $, or, equivalently, if and only if $\ 2^{6400}\ $ is the smallest positive integer $\ n\ $ such that $\ f\ $ divides $\ x^{n-1}-1\ $.  The Magma script below shows that $\ f\ $ is primitive over $\ GF(2)\ $, so it divides $\ x^{2^{80}-1}-1\ $, all its roots are primitive elements of $\ GF\left(2^{80}\right)\ $ and it splits completely into linear factors over that field. It's therefore not even irreducible over $\ GF\left(2^{80}\right)\ $, let alone primitive.

The object $\ f\ $ in your second script is a completely different animal.  Here, $\ x\ $ is *not* an indeterminate of any polynomial ring at all, but a primitive element in the field $\ GF\left(2^{80}\right)\ $, and so $\ f\ $, being a polynomial function of $\ x\ $, is also just another element of $\ GF\left(2^{80}\right)\ $. By definition, it's primitive if and only if $\ 2^{80}-1\ $ is the smallest positive integer $\ m\ $ such that $\ f^m=1\ $.  If it's not primitive then you must have $\ f^\frac{2^{80}-1}{p}=1\ $ for one of  the prime factors $\ p\ $ of $\ 2^{80}-1\ $, and it's easy enough to use the Magma calculator to check that this isn't the case.

Here's a Magma script to verify all the assertions made above:

```
K<y>:=GF(2^80);
IsPrimitive(y);
R<x>:=PolynomialRing(K);
S<z>:=PolynomialRing(GF(2));
Factorization(2^80-1);
f1:=1 + y^18 + y^29 + y^42 + y^57 + y^67 + y^80;
f2:=1 + x^18 + x^29 + x^42 + x^57 + x^67 + x^80;
f3:=1 + z^18 + z^29 + z^42 + z^57 + z^67 + z^80;
IsPrimitive(f3);
f1^((2^80-1) div 3);
f1^((2^80-1) div 5);
f1^((2^80-1) div 11);
f1^((2^80-1) div 17);
f1^((2^80-1) div 31);
f1^((2^80-1) div 41);
f1^((2^80-1) div 257);
f1^((2^80-1) div 61681);
f1^((2^80-1) div 4278255361);
Factorization(f2);
```

Comment: The two largest prime factors are $(2^{20}+1)/(2^4+1)$ and $(2^{40}+1)/(2^8+1)$. +1 was there already.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thank you for your comment, but I'm wondering if you're trying to point out a deficiency in my answer that needs correcting.  If so, I don't understand what it is.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @lonza leggiera !

Comment: Not at all. It was more like thinking aloud about finding the factorization. Those two factors are easy to find by hand. Proving they are primes on the other hand. Very sorry about leaving you wondering. Those were all CAS outputs, and that is unavoidable here.